# How to get the variable value outside sh part in Jenkins?

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I was trying to store the output of for loop in in varble and use it outside sh part.

I have declared the lambda_deployers outside pipeline as

`def lambda_deployers=""`

```
        
        stage('Fetch lambda paths') {
            steps {
                
                sh '''
                        cd $WORKDIR/$BASE_DIR/
                        for k in $(find . -type f -name 'package.json')
                        do
                            FILE_PATH=$(echo "${k}" | cut -c 2-)
                            DIR_PATH=$(dirname "$FILE_PATH" | cut -c 2-)
                            lambda_deployers+="/$BASE_DIR/$DIR_PATH"
                        done
                     echo $lambda_deployers
                        
                     ''' 
                     sh """echo $lambda_deployers"""
                 
                
                
            }
        }
```

The first echo inside sh ''' '''  works but one outside sh ''' '''  doesn't

Also tried with declaring it as env variable and adding sh ''' under script

```
          environment {
       
        LAMBDA_BASE_DIR="lambda"
        lambda_deployers=""
     
     
    }
stage('Fetch lambda paths') {
            steps {
                script{
                
                sh '''
                        cd $WORKDIR/$BASE_DIR/
                        for k in $(find . -type f -name 'package.json')
                        do
                            FILE_PATH=$(echo "${k}" | cut -c 2-)
                            DIR_PATH=$(dirname "$FILE_PATH" | cut -c 2-)
                            lambda_deployers+="/$BASE_DIR/$DIR_PATH"
                        done
                        echo $lambda_deployers
                  
                     ''' 
                       echo "${env.lambda_deployers}"
                 
                }
```

The echo outside sh ''' displays as null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign values to Pipeline variables from within Shell blocks. Few different ways to achieve what you need, write the output to a file and then read from that file when you want to use the variable. Or return the standard out of the `sh` block and assign it to the variable. Something like below.

```
lambda_deployers = sh (
    script: '''
          cd $WORKDIR/$BASE_DIR/
          for k in $(find . -type f -name 'package.json')
          do
              FILE_PATH=$(echo "${k}" | cut -c 2-)
              DIR_PATH=$(dirname "$FILE_PATH" | cut -c 2-)
              lambda_deployers+="/$BASE_DIR/$DIR_PATH"
          done
          echo $lambda_deployers
        ''',
    returnStdout: true
).trim()
```

**Update**
Full Pipeline

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('Wrapper') {
      steps {
        script {
            lambda_deployers = sh (
                    script: '''
                          cd $WORKDIR/$BASE_DIR/
                          for k in $(find . -type f -name 'package.json')
                          do
                              FILE_PATH=$(echo "${k}" | cut -c 2-)
                              DIR_PATH=$(dirname "$FILE_PATH" | cut -c 2-)
                              lambda_deployers+="/$BASE_DIR/$DIR_PATH"
                          done
                          echo "this is test content"
                        ''',
                    returnStdout: true
                ).trim()
            
            echo "$lambda_deployers"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in pipeline{stage{}} part. Do i need to run it in node{}?

Comment: @yrc This was perfect. Worked like a charm. Thanks a lot. I've been struggling with this a lot

Answer (score 0):

Add a script inside steps like this

````
environment {
    lambda_deployers=""
}
stage('Fetch lambda paths') {
    steps {
        script{
            sh '''
                cd $WORKDIR/$BASE_DIR/
                for k in $(find . -type f -name 'package.json')
                do
                    FILE_PATH=$(echo "${k}" | cut -c 2-)
                    DIR_PATH=$(dirname "$FILE_PATH" | cut -c 2-)
                    lambda_deployers+="/$BASE_DIR/$DIR_PATH"
                done
                echo $lambda_deployers
                        
            ''' 
            sh """echo $lambda_deployers"""
        }  
     
    }
}
```
````

Comment: Yus! Tried still the same

Comment: if you define the "lambda_deployers" in the "environment" block and change its variable inside a script block then it will take his last change

Comment: i updated that part in question. Let me know if i missed something

Comment: yes, like this in the environment pipeline block the global block , still doesn't work?